# React use variable in .setState

Tags: reactjs

In my function I need to pass a variable to the .setState function but I'm not able to solve this issue. I'm rather new to React so I hope someone can help me out. My code is like this:

```
  public componentDidMount(){
    var reactHandler = this;
    var Xresults = {}; 

    jquery.ajax({
      //url: `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeList')/items`,
      url: "https://blabla.sharepoint.com/sites/ilss/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:test_matters'&selectproperties='RefinableString10%2cCreatedBy%2cCreated'&rowlimit=500'",

      type: "GET",
      headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},
      success: function(resultData) {               
        for(var i=0;i<resultData.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows;i++){
          Xresults [resultData.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[2].Key] = resultData.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[2].value;
        }

        reactHandler.setState({
          items: Xresults
        });
      },
      error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      }
   });
 }
```

in the .setState "Xresults" is not available. How do I pass this?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: There seems to be a space between Xresults and [resultData...]. That could be an issue.

Comment: you may also try    }.bind(this)); to close ajax call instead of });

Comment: If it all fails you may try fetch (axios) and arrow functions. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866876/how-to-setstate-to-new-data-in-react

Comment: Thanks, the space is not an issue (I do not have that in my original code. caused by pasting).

Comment: The "bind" did also not solve it. Keeps giving me errors (visual studio .code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my global variable is not accessible within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494071/why-my-global-variable-is-not-accessible-within-a-function)

Comment: Does it work if you use `let` instead: `let Xresults = {};` ?